# Kotlin Data Class: How generate an MongoDB ObjectId for an embedded document

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, spring-boot, kotlin

I'm building an API with Spring Boot and Kotlin. I am trying to generate a structure the following way in MongoDB.

[image]

I understand that in MongoDb the concept of relationships between entities does not exist, so I will use the strategy of embedded documents. That is, to embed the Reunión in the Proyecto, and the Participante in the Reunión.

I have a main class called `Proyecto` and `NewProyecto`, that contains as property a list of reuniones of type `NewReunion`. I use two different classes to create and return data.

**Proyecto.kt**

```
@Document(collection = "proyectos")
@TypeAlias("proyecto")
data class Proyecto (
        @Id
        val id: String,
        val nombre: String,
        val area: String,
        val fecha:String,
        val reuniones: List<Reunion>?
){}

@Document(collection = "proyectos")
@TypeAlias("newproyecto")
data class NewProyecto (
        @Id
        val id: String?,//Es posiblemente nulo porqué se crea automáticamente
        var nombre: String,
        var area: String,
        var fecha:String,
        var reuniones: List<NewReunion>?
){}
```

Now, to create 'reuniones' I have two classes, `Reunion` and `NewReunion`. The class that corresponds to create a MongoDB embedded document is `NewReunion`.

**NewReunion.kt**

```
@Document
data class Reunion(
        val objetivo: String,
        val fecha: String,
        val participantes: List<Participante>?
) {}

@Document
data class NewReunion(
        var id: String? = ObjectId().toHexString(),
        var fecha: String,
        var participantes: List<NewParticipante>?
) {}
```

This is where I have the problem. I want to generate an ObjectId for this `NewReunion` class, so that each object embedded in it has an `id`. The problem is that `ObjectId ().ToHexString()` is not generating any value at the time that the object of type `NewReunion` is built, but the other data that are `objetivo` and `fecha` are filled with the data that comes from the request POST.

**How I send the information.**

The information I send via `POST`. This request is handled by a Controller named `ProyectoController.kt`

**ProyectoController.kt**

```
@PostMapping("/")
fun createProyecto(@RequestBody newProyecto: NewProyecto): NewProyecto = proyectoService.createProyecto(newProyecto)
```

**ProyectoRepository.kt**

```
interface ProyectoRepository : MongoRepository<Proyecto, String> {
    fun findById(id: ObjectId): Proyecto
    override fun findAll(): List<Proyecto>
    fun insert(proyecto: NewProyecto): NewProyecto
    fun save(proyect: Proyecto): Proyecto
    fun deleteById(id: ObjectId)
}
```

**ProyectoService.kt**

```
@Service("proyectoService")
class ProyectoServiceImpl : ProyectoService {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var proyectoRepository: ProyectoRepository

    //Obtener un proyecto
    override fun findById(id: ObjectId): Proyecto = proyectoRepository.findById(id)

    //Obtener todos los proyectos
    override fun findAll(): List<Proyecto> = proyectoRepository.findAll()

    //Crear un proyecto
    override fun createProyecto(newProyecto: NewProyecto): NewProyecto = proyectoRepository.insert(newProyecto)

    //Actualizar un proyecto
    override fun updateProyecto(proyecto: Proyecto):Proyecto = proyectoRepository.save(proyecto)

    //Eliminar un proyecto
    override fun deleteProyecto(id:ObjectId) = proyectoRepository.deleteById(id)
}
```

**POST using Postman:**

To send the information I am using Postman, and I send the request in the following way.
[image]

At the time of creating the new `Proyecto`, I return it to see the result which returns a result with **`id=null`**, but all other fields do assign the corresponding value:

[image]

Now, I tried initializing all the constructor parameters of the NewReunion class to see what happened.

```
data class NewReunion(
        @Id
        var id: String? = ObjectId().toHexString(),
        var objetivo: String = "",
        var fecha: String = ""
) {}
```

the value for the `id` is generated correctly together with the other values. It is just this behavior that I do not understand why I need to initialize constructor parameters of the `NewReunion` class.

**Result of POST with the parameters initialized.**

[image]

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.71'
        springBootVersion = '2.0.6.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}")
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'war'

group = 'com.gibranlara'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version" // Required for Kotlin integration
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb"
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
}
```

Comment: where does it get values for `objetivo` and `fecha` if they were empty? I think that examples are not complete. Also I think this post lacks information about used libraries

Comment: @asm0dey `objetivo` and `fecha` when creating a new instance should not be empty, so I do not have the properties marked with `?`. The information comes from a post made with postman.

Comment: @asm0dey I have edited my question to give more context.

Comment: Which library are you using (where `@Document` etc. are from)? How are you using these classes?

Comment: I think this question is not really about kotlin or mongodb, but is about some library which is neither mentioned nor tagged

Comment: What happens when you annotate your constructor with @JvmOverloads?

Comment: Optional parameters should normally go to the end.

Comment: @asm0dey No, I'm not using any library. It is only a spring boot application programming with kotlin. If I had a library, I would have mentioned it.

Comment: @Gibrán, my Spanish does not extend beyond the ability to order a beer without hand gestures, I understand there are "projects" and "participants", not sure what is meant by "Reunion". Is it possible to translate some of it?

Comment: @Gibrán, also share your dependency list, I need to see if you are using some kind of no-args plugin.

Comment: Ok @AndreArtus , I have added my `build.gradle` file. Regarding the reunión, a 'reunión' is a meeting of people. A project can have many work meetings, and the meetings are made up of participants.

Comment: @Gibrán, I've put up a demo of what I think you want to achieve, check it out. https://github.com/andre-artus/kotlin-optional-param-spring-demo
If that look like what you want I can explain it further here.

Comment: @AndreArtus Exactly that is what I was trying to do! Thank you very very much. Yes, I have some doubts, but I can ask you where you indicate me, either in git or in here :)

Comment: Cool. You should probably edit your question to reflect that you were having an issue using Kotlin default parameters in Spring Boot. The question as it stands now is probably not very helpful to others, which is probably why someone down-voted it. You can raise an issue on the GitHub repo I posted if you want to discuss this further. Or take it to chat.

Comment: @Gibrán, I will also add that if your intention is to build a REST API then this is not the correct approach. You are using the Web MVC features best suited for web pages. Even if you are calling into your endpoints to populate a page through [adjective].JS you should rather prefer the REST API features.

Comment: @AndreArtus An apology, but I'm afraid I do not know what the difference is. I thought they were the same :/.

Comment: @Gibrán, not quite, I'll discuss this with you over on GH.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The library you are using is probably not written with Kotlin in mind.

Kotlin generates a synthetic constructor that loads default values prior to calling the actual constructor, e.g.

```
   // Java 
   public NewReunion(String var1, String var2, String var3, int var4, DefaultConstructorMarker var5) {
      if ((var4 & 1) != 0) {
         var1 = ObjectId().toHexString();
      }
      this(var1, var2, var3);
   }
```

The library is likely doing one of the following:

- Calling the default constructor, then calling set[Property] matching the annotations/convention.
- Calling the closest match constructor: `NewReunion(@Nullable String id, @NotNull String objetivo, @NotNull String fecha)` with `NewReunion(null, "objetivo", "fecha")`

If you define your class as such:

```
data class NewReunion @JvmOverloads constructor(
    var id: String? = "",
    var objetivo: String,
    var fecha: String
)
```

You will get additional constructors e.g.

```
// Java
public NewReunion(@NotNull String objetivo, @NotNull String fecha)
```

If your library is using the first option then you may need to lazy initialize the `id` field in a getter (also convert data class to normal class).

### *An Aside*

Most of these kind of problems stem from devs using the same object model for communication and business logic. Whenever I see a nullable `id` on an entity it like a clarion call that bugs are afoot.

Any data you get from an outside source(even if it's from a server you control) should be treated as if it was put there by your most baleful enemy, but many developers just suck it in and use it as it comes.

If you don't have something along the lines of

```
val cleanData = validate(inputData)
```

before crossing from an input layer to a business layer then you are setting yourself up for future embarrassment.

Input layers are:

- User interface
- Web services
- Anything coming from outside your immediate domain of control

Comment: But I'm not using any library. I just initialize a new spring boot application, added the kotlin dependency and that's all.

I'm using the NewReunion model only for creation. The id is null because I am not sending the ObjectId from the fron-end, but I want that when a NewReunion object is generated it generates an objectid for that object. To return the information I am using a model called Proyecto, which does not allow for null values.

Comment: If you are using Spring Boot then you are using not one, but many [Java] libraries.

See my advice above, under "An Aside". The two models, even if they look [almost] the same, should not be forced into one. You should really have some logic in-between the two that maps from the input model (NewReunion?) to the output model (Proyecto?). That mapping function should be responsible for ensuring all fields are valid, incl.ObjectId. Use the type system to your advantage.

Comment: Currently I have my model, controllers, repositories and services. I just do not know at what point it is where I should generate the id for the embedded document (NewReunion). If you allow me I can place all my code to give more context, what do you think?

Comment: That's cool, I'll have to look at it later though, as it is bedtime for me.

Comment: I appreciate your time and help, rest.